# Angular : How does binding with expression work?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

```
<section class="slide-show" ng-style="getBgStyle()">
   hello
</section>
```

In the controller :

```
$scope.getBgStyle = function(){
  return "{'background-color':'blue'}";
}
```

No colour is shown. But with :

```
<section class="slide-show" ng-style="{{getBgStyle()}}">
   hello
</section>
```

This does work. As from the documention, ng-style expects an "expression".

This is a very common question about expression, and I suppose 'x' versus '{{x}}' has been asked 1000 times. Is there a difference with function calls ?

Comment: That is because you have a valid JSON and angular parses the expression using $parse while doing the binding in the interpolation  (`{{}}`), which returns the object from JSON. Just try doing `$parse("{'background-color':'blue'}")()`

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/interpolate.js#L205

Answer (score 0):

This is a very funky (I'm surprised that it works) way of using an expression.

Have your `getBgStyle` function return an object instead - rather than a string that could be `$eval`-ed to an object:

```
$scope.getBgStyle = function(){
  return {'background-color':'blue'};
}

<section class="slide-show" ng-style="getBgStyle()">
   hello
</section>
```

**EDIT**:

The funny thing is, both of the following expressions work:

```
ng-style="{'background-color': 'blue'}"
ng-style="{{ {'background-color': 'blue'} }}"
```